# QGIS saving analysis output as Postgis table

Tags: qgis, postgis, esri-geodatabase, openjump

i am using **QGIS and Postgis** together. I can load data in Postgis and than i import it to QGIS. But i am trying to **save an analysis output (example: buffer analysis, voronoi polygon or SEXTANTE analysis tools) directly in Postgis**. Is there anyway to make this?

For instance in ArcGIS you can save an analysis output in a **.GDB .MDB geodatabase** but in QGIS  firstly i save an output as .SHP than i load it to Postgis or in OpenJump after analysis you must save layer in Postgis table. So there is one more step !

Comment: The set of analysis tools in the fTools extensions are all designed to save only as shapefile, AFAIK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the SEXTANTE tool called "import into PostGIS". You should define a connection and then use the nae of that connection as input to that module.

If the algorithm that generates the result you want to import is also a SEXTANTE one (like the voronoi one you mention), you can create a small model to put everything in a single operation

Direct output to a database is something I started working on in SEXTANTE, but there is some work to do before it's ready to be used...

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [DB Manager Plugin](http://docs.qgis.org/html/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_db_manager.html)

Comment: I have been using DB Manager for a long time but it is not solution for my question

Comment: From the page I linked you to: "You can drag layers from the QGIS Browser into the DB Manager and it will import your layer into your spatial database."  Seems like a solution to me.